# Stokes Theorem for Cone/Plane Intersection

Tags: stokes-theorem

> Evaluate the line integral
>   $$I = \int_C F \cdot ds$$
>   when 
>   $F(x,y,z) = \langle x+2z, 0, y \rangle$
>   and $C$ is the curve of intersection of the cone $z^2 = x^2+y^2$ with the plane $2z = -x+2$.

So I am trying to use Stokes' Theorem here and can compute $curl(F) = \vec{i} + 2\vec{j}$. It's parametrizing the intersection that I'm having trouble with. I am trying to do $z = -\frac{x}{2}+1$ and then letting my curve be
$$u(r,t) = \langle r\cos t, r\sin t, -\frac{r}{2}\cos(t)+1 \rangle $$
and then computing $u_r \times u_t$. But this parametrization seems off to me. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given the solution in the handwritten image. Hopefully it is clear and legible

[image]

Comment: Im getting  8pi/3root(3) uisng Stoke's theorem